# Why am I getting different Wi-Fi speeds from two different PCs in the same room?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, motherboard

I recently bought the [TP-Link AC 1300](https://www.tp-link.com/us/home-networking/pci-adapter/archer-t6e/) PCIe Wi-Fi adapter, plugged it into my desktop’s motherboard and installed the drivers.

The router ([GPON HS8247W EchoLife](https://support.huawei.com/enterprise/en/access-network/echolife-hg8247u-pid-22477390)) delivers 500 Mbps and is in a different room. My laptop is an ASUS Zenbook 14 and the download speed in my room is around 230 Mbps, which has an ([Intel(R) Wireless-AC 9560 160 MHz](https://www.intel.la/content/www/xl/es/products/docs/wireless-products/dual-band-wireless-ac-9560-brief.html))

However, the desktop in my room is only getting around 7 Mbps. How is that possible? Can the motherboard ([MSI z170-A PRO](https://us.msi.com/Motherboard/Z170-A-PRO/Overview)) be the reason?

Comment: What is the model of router you are using? It could all be a Wi-Fi speed negotiation issue. One idea is to test if you can by connecting to your router at 802.11n only. And then just connect at 802.11g only. And see if there is a pattern. I have a funny feeling that the issue is simply Wi-Fi protocol issues. 802.11n is known to have issues communicating via the same protocol — but via different devices — on the same network.

Comment: The router is GPON HS8247W EchoLife. I have to admit i'm not very familiar with the some of the technical terms, but I'll try my best to keep up :)  Firstly: where can I change the 802.11n or 802.11g connection?

Comment: Usually in the router wireless settings. If you don't have them there, in **windows** you can go to device manager -> your WLAN adapter, and if the drivers have the option you can force 802.11B/G/N. In **Linux** I believe it would be **IW** from the terminal of your choice. **This is probably just a difference in the Wlan adapters hardware capabilities. Please add the make model of both adapters to the question**

Comment: @Tim_Stewart I have gone to the advanced settings of my network adapter and i'm tweaking the Band preference setting which tells me I can choose 802.11 a or 802.11 g/b. Should I be changing a different setting? Also, and I'm very sorry for my ignorance, what do you mean by "make" model? And for both adapters do you mean the adapters in the desktop and laptop?

Comment: Currently, side by side in the same room, the wireless negotiation speeds are 39 Mbps and 585Mbps (this varies between 390 and this number) for my desktop and laptop respectively.

Comment: What exactly is *"side by side"*?  WiFi is radio, and RF reflections within a room can create deadspots and hotspots.   The antenna placement & orientation are crucial.  Your laptop has its antenna in the lid, which is sticking up in clear air for good reception.  Your desktop has a PCIe Wi-Fi adapter, and its antennae are down low in the back of the case.  Try a radical experiment: situate the desktop upside-down so that the antennae can be extended straight out & vertical in open air for best reception.

Comment: I have my desktop under a wooden table and I placed my laptop on the floor right beside the desktop and measured the speeds. Even with a powerline connected on a plug inside the same very room, the desktop only achieves around 16 Mbps. I know tried in different positions and still got the same results.

Comment: I just brought the desktop right next to the router and speeds reach only 13 Mbps. I would assume that that takes care of all experiments regarding different positions

Comment: Actually I have an update: With my desktop right next to the router, I was fiddling with the antennas (loosening them, screwing them tighter, having them fully extended horizontally, folded, etc..) and there were times i would only reach 2 mbps and others I would reach around 350 Mbps. Even for the same configuration of the antennas, i would vary. Can the antennas have some problem?

Comment: More update: so, for different configurations of the antenna and even for the same configurations, there are drastic reductions and augments of speed which almost looks like a completely stochastic phenomenon. I tried some old antenaas from a previous TP link adapter model and they worked much better (still right next to the router). So I suspect the new antenna came defective. I'll be trying on my room once again.

Comment: Just went back to my room and I'm getting the old results again even with the other pair of antennas :(